# joomla template problem post installation

Tags: joomla

I have created a template and it was successfully installed in joomla.However I can only find its listing under  the templates tab of extensions manager , not under the Template manager  .Can any body help?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Joomla are you using? Is it 1.5? Template installation package shold have a file called templateDetails.xml and the file should contain name of template:

```
<name>template name</name>
```

Have you compared your `templateDetails.xml` with that file from one of the default templates? Are they similiar? Try to copy that file from default template and insert your specific data and other leave other infomation as is.

I hope it is helpfull.